# How do we deal with massive author retag?

Tags: discussion, retagging, suggested-edit

I'm not a usual reviewer but I occasionally try to give a hand. Lately I've met a lot of suggested edits retagging `brandon-sanderson` in any question related with his works, not questions about the author himself.

Following this [question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7923/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-individual-works-tags-vs-author-tags-vs-franchise) I assume it's an unnecessary retag and reject it, nonetheless I see the active questions list is full of these retagged questions.

Am I correct in rejecting the edits? Should I erase the other retags? How should we proceed so as not to start an edit war?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT:** I've just completed the retagging of questions about Sanderson and his works. In future, **please use the [brandon-sanderson](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brandon-sanderson) tag only for questions about the author, and individual work tags, along with [cosmere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmere) [if the work is part of the Cosmere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/147052/31394), as described [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10287/31394).**

---

I recently posted [a question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10284/31394) here on meta in order to try to pin down what tagging policy we should be following for the works of Brandon Sanderson. The [consensus](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10287/31394) there was that we should be using [brandon-sanderson](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brandon-sanderson) only for questions about the author himself and using [cosmere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmere) as the franchise tag covering all his works (which is roughly what [brandon-sanderson](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brandon-sanderson) is *currently* being used for).

We still need to sort out the tagging of the existing questions, of course. This will be done by making a list of which questions are sufficiently author-oriented to merit the [brandon-sanderson](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brandon-sanderson) tag, then merging that tag into [cosmere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmere) and re-adding it manually to those few questions. This task is high up on my to-do list, and I'll start on it as soon as I've finished [sorting out the author-ID tag](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10373/31394).

In the meantime, I'll make the user who's been suggesting those edits aware of the above-linked meta post about Sanderson tags, and ask them to hold off on further such edits until the time comes to properly sort out the [brandon-sanderson](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brandon-sanderson) and [cosmere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmere) tags (at which point, of course, they'll be very welcome to help with the *necessary* retagging).

**TL;DR: let's *all* hold off on Sanderson retagging until we know exactly what needs to be done.**

Comment: Or we could hold off doing anything at all. Always a fine option, oft not considered.

Comment: @Valorum Thanks for your input, but that option was already considered on the linked meta post and the consensus was otherwise.

Comment: I don't think the relevant parties got this memo....

Comment: @Radhil Well, [that question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/94952) needs the Cosmere tag *whatever* our tagging policy is, since it's about the Cosmere as a whole. They did [get my ping](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=33797619#33797619).

Comment: On the topic of retagging [tag:Brandon-Sanderson] work to the [tag:Cosmere] tag, would a question like [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147128/what-is-the-difference-between-a-wizard-and-a-magician) need to be retagged to something other than [tag:tolkien], possibly [tag:tales-from-the-perilous-realm] (which is a non existing tag) to keep it consistent, or is this change only happening with [tag:brandon-sanderson] and [tag:cosemre] ?

Comment: @Edlothiad I retagged that particular question (I'd already been planning to, having noticed it earlier while not logged in), but in general, sorting out our Tolkien tags is a very big operation which will have to be organised carefully, and which I don't think we're really ready to embark on yet. (Mass retags can be controversial around here!) See also [Let's figure out our Tolkien tags](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10160/31394).