# Artist-ID from artwork sample or artwork description. On-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There is some specific Fantasy artwork (1980 or earlier era) for which I would like to find out who was the artist. The style is extremely distinctive and I remember back in the day such imagery was used on book-covers and illustrations in books and magazines.
In this particular case I don't actually have any samples to post, but I can mock up a sketch that clearly demonstrates the distinctive trademark style aspects, which should be recognizable to anyone who is familiar with this artist's work.

For other cases I can envision posting some sample pictures (I have pictures, but I don't know where they came from. Copyright status might be problematic, but that is an entirely different question.)

Would an Artist-ID question be on-topic for this site? The Faq and help-center don't give much guidance on artwork-id, but to me it is somewhat similar as story-id questions.
If it is on-topic I would like to suggest an Artist-ID tag might be useful as well.

P.S. I asked a question [see here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159907/origin-of-old-drawings-before-1995-of-defrog-space-craft) a little over 2 years ago on a somewhat similar subject which didn't get any votes to close. But it isn't exactly the same thing either. I only added the image in that question later to provide further clarification.

Comment: [Ask away dude](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes these are on topic** and I don't see why they shouldn't be. As long as the artwork is clearly science fictional and/or fantastical it is perfectly fine to ask about.

To avoid any doubt we have had several question in the past that asked to ID an artist or artwork, for example

- [Wanderers of Time & Next of Kin Cover artist](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12780/58193),
- [Help me Identify Strange and Bizarre Fantasy Artist, World Was Similar to Dragons Lair Game](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/181659/58193) and
- [SF artwork identification - painting of woman looking through a playing card](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176078/58193)

Looking through these most appear to use [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) with [art](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/art) or [cover-art](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cover-art). I don't really see the need for a more specific [artist-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artist-identification) tag especially considering it was decided to [nuke the [author-identification] tag](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10288/58193).

The normal guidelines when asking are in place i.e.

- Provide information to state how it is SFF-nal
- Provide as much extra information as possible

  - Where did you see it (artbook, cover art etc.),
  - When did you see it
  - And so on.

See the [general story id guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) for some more tips if you need them.

Comment: I wonder why this answer got a down-vote? If you don't agree please clarify why.

Comment: @Tonny Whoever downvoted it, appears to have downvoted the question too. Some people just don't like tag discussions which this is in part.

Comment: I didn't even notice the downvote on the question itself. You could be right on the tag-issue. Happens a lot on SuperUser and StackOverflow as well.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - This is less of a tag discussion and more of a scope discussion though. Either way, it's firmly on-topic and I look forward to seeing the question.

Comment: @Valorum Aye I know, it does touch on tags though.

Comment: There's also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32255/book-cover-art-desert-with-mesas-and-a-city-ship-on-top/32565#32565; I definitely agree it's on-topic.

Comment: @DavidW Aye there's certainly others, I just linked to a couple of examples.

Comment: @Valorum: Between this question and *The Truman Show* one, I get the sense that some people just don't like finding out that thing X is on-topic. Which is a shame, because it's really easy to ignore tags.