# Should we kill all the [authors]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed that we have a tag [authors](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authors). This seems fairly useless: it's impossible for someone to be an expert in "authors" generally; we already allow tags for specific authors, and what does it even mean for a question to be "about authors" in general?

There are currently **38 questions** with this tag, which can be categorised as follows:

### About a specific author

- [Is there a backup of Ray Aldridge's site with his stories?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/260827/)
- [Was there really an author called Allen Sharp?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/215226/)
- [Any details on Dannie Plachta's bio and name pronunciation?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/197006/)
- [Did Paul Richards (author of "The Unblessed") write anything else?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43690/)
- [Is there a way to get in touch with Barry Hughart?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45808/) [closed]
- [Who was Gavin Hyde and what happened to him?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237618/)
- [Pronunciation of Van Vogt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49602/)
- [Looking for any biographical info on Terence Haile, author of Space Train](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13229/)
- [Why did Gene Roddenberry write a letter together with three Harvard-Smithsonian astronomers about the planet Vulcan?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195152/)
- [Has Max Brooks ever discussed the possibility of writing more zombie books?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97650/)
- [Has anyone else written about Terry Pratchett's other worlds?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14650/) [closed]
- [Bio of Donald A. Wollheim](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103327/)
- [Why did Iain M. Banks use his middle initial for his science fiction writing, but go by 'Iain Banks' in other works?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259237/)
- [What influence did H.P. Lovecraft have on science fiction?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/268/)
- [Doc Savage’s fighting style](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/271391/)

### Author identification

- [Author of "military squad" SF podcast](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/245682/)
- [Successful author who began writing while completely disabled](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171702/)
- [Who said, "The only way to model an infinitely complex system is with the system, itself"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258709/)
- [Who is the author "DT in Oakland"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/178214/31394)
- [What author joked that his writing skill came from a magical amulet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/233435/)

### Basically bog-standard story-ID

- [What book(s) reference dates A.S. (After Shannon) and what is the in-universe explanation for its origin?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/262876/)
- [Author of a short story in a compilation or high school textbook for a Sci-Fi extra credit course](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161805/)
- [Looking for a novel (or author of it) where the world is a seemlingly endless vertical cliff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79305/) [duplicate]
- [Vintage short story of school kids studying a lethal alien design](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266701/) [duplicate]
- [Looking for an author's anthology of short surreal/absurdist fiction (80s-90s)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221980/)
- [A paperback collection of letters between Isaac Asimov and Arthur C. Clarke](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223293/)
- [Identify the author of an anthology, which included a story about an alien working in City Lights bookshop](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255165/)

### Other

- [Best way to stay informed on an author without much of a web presence?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6908/)
- [Can the creator of a fictional universe get their own lore wrong?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180386/) [closed]
- [Authorship of Forgotten Realms novels](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/230755/31394)
- [Who wrote "The Monsters" short story published by Purnell?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117600/31394)
- [What is the "About the Author" blurb in Shadows of the Empire supposed to say?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/118387/)
- [Who was the first Science Fiction author to have a celestial body named after them?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60385/)
- [Old site with the religious affiliations of most science fiction writers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259991/)
- [Parody names of SF writers in Damon Knight story](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260437/)
- [Who *really* wrote the Rama sequels?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1685/)
- [How closely did When Worlds Collide authors pursue the physics of the catastrophic damage and planet trajectories?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/198302/31394)
- [Do authors ever create conflicting canon to irk fussy fans?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40934/) [closed]

Certainly some of these don't need to have an [authors](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authors) tag, but do any of them? **Should we keep the [authors](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authors) tag - and, if so, what usage guidance should it have - or is it too vague to be useful?**

<sub>Relevant reading: [What to do with the [author-identification] tag?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10282/31394) Apparently we had an [author-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/author-identification) tag before and got rid of it (and apparently I was part of that process, but I don't remember it). My feeling now is to reintroduce it, as a useful way of identifying a half-remembered author without reference to a single specific story, but let's see what other people think.</sub>

Comment: Oh, goodness, your title is rich....I had to pause and laugh before reading the (also good!) question!

Comment: @Basya :-) it's a bit of a tradition here to give punny titles to tag burnination requests on meta.

Comment: Well, I certainly enjoyed this one!

Comment: I really only see a few questions that might really warrant this tag, and don't have a better option.  But I am not sure what we should do, for example, with a question like, "Looking for any biographical info on Terence Haile, author of Space Train".  There's not a [terence-haile] tag and it seems that it would be unlikely we'd want one....

Comment: @Basya I think if we start having those questions, there's definitely scope to create that tag.

Comment: -1 for the cute title.

Comment: Personally, I think that the [author] tag is appropriate if the question is about the author.  Presumably a tag about a [specific-author] might be used for question about their canon of work and non the author themselves.  And in other cases, there is no such [specific-author] tag.

Answer (score 9):

Here's what I'd propose we do with these:

- About a specific author - create a tag for that author
- Author identification - create/use [author-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/author-identification)
- Basically bog-standard story-ID - delete the tag
- Other ... various tag suggestions

- [Best way to stay informed on an author without much of a web presence?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6908/) - not an exact fit but [fandom](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fandom)/[behind-the-scenes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behind-the-scenes)
- [Can the creator of a fictional universe get their own lore wrong?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180386/) [closed] - Unclear, but could be re-asked as a 'first of' so [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of)
- [Authorship of Forgotten Realms novels](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/230755/31394) -??? [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of)
- [Who wrote "The Monsters" short story published by Purnell?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117600/31394) - [author-id](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/author-id)
- [What is the "About the Author" blurb in Shadows of the Empire supposed to say?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/118387/) - [behind-the-scenes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behind-the-scenes)
- [Who was the first Science Fiction author to have a celestial body named after them?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60385/) - [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of)
- [Old site with the religious affiliations of most science fiction writers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259991/) - ??? [fandom](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fandom)
- [Parody names of SF writers in Damon Knight story](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260437/) - delete tag
- [Who *really* wrote the Rama sequels?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1685/) - delete tag
- [How closely did When Worlds Collide authors pursue the physics of the catastrophic damage and planet trajectories?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/198302/31394) - delete tag
- [Do authors ever create conflicting canon to irk fussy fans?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40934/) [closed] - could be re-asked as a [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of).

Comment: Some of these are a bit of a stretch -- though my main issue would be that a lot of askers would not necessarily make these associations and it might be hard for them (us..) to pick the right tag.

author-id no longer exists -- are you suggesting removing [authors] and reinstating [author-identification]?

Comment: @Basya yeah these are definitely on the spandex side of stretchy.  People may not make the right association straight away, but we can teach people. Also, I don't think [author-id] nor [author-identification] exist yet, but one would be a synonym for the other

Comment: There was an author-identification tag and it was removed, for good reason.  That meta question is linked to this one already.

Comment: Maybe a [tag:disputed-authorship] tag when the authorship is disputed.